# Is the seed in BLAST expanded to the left and right sides into HSP?

Tags: bioinformatics, blast

In the BLAST algorithm, I understand that the rule for seed expansion used to define high scoring pair (HSP) on both sides is when the score decreases (negative number).

However I find that even if the score is negative, it continues to expand to both sides. Why?

Comment: This question may be more appropriate for [Bioinformatics Stack Exchange](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

BLAST does not necessarily stop the expansion each time the score decreases.
In fact, it only stops the expansion, if the score drops below some certain cutoff which is called **drop-off**.